# How do I remove the "Switch Input Method" icon from my desktop?

Tags: lubuntu, input-method

There is a small icon in the corner of my screen in Lubuntu 12.04. It looks like this:

[image]

The computer runs a display monitor and I need to remove the icon, I can drag it around including off the screen, but after each reboot it goes back into the corner. Any ideas on how I can remove this icon? It's got me stumped.

Comment: It could be the IBus GUI, try `pkill -f ibus-ui-gtk3`

Answer (score 0):

My computer with Lubuntu 14.04 32 bits has got the IBus icon in the taskbar, but it does not look like that. I can make a right click on it and ask it not to appear.

You can also check the autostart application in "default applications for LXSession" in the preferences sub-menu. You might solve this by disabling that "known application" in the autostart tab.

Anyway, Lubuntu 14.04 has already been released.

PS: I am aware that Ubuntu 14.04.1 has already been released, but I cannot find any single piece of news of Lubuntu 14.04.1 at www.lubuntu.net. However, it is true that lsb_release command shows that my computer is running Ubuntu 14.04.1. Any improvement in my poor message will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

What actually looks like an icon is indeed the **Show language panel** of ibus.
Right click the ibus icon in your panel/taskbar (see 1st answer).
In the shown menu, left click **Preferences**.
Under **Font and Style**, for **Show language panel**, choose other than Always.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Keyboard Input Methods in IBus Preferences go to Show language panel: and set it to Embedded in menu